# How do I create a column based on other columns in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

For example,

I'm trying to create a Color column based on a Feeling column. If Feeling == Angry, Color = Red. Otherwise, Color = Blue. At the same time, I'm trying to pull data from another column as well. Let's say, If Temperature == Hot, Color = Red; otherwise Color = Blue.

Is there a step in Pentaho that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not one step that can do both of these, but it can be done with a combination of steps. Look at the `Value mapper`, the `Calculator`, and the `Set field value` steps. For more complex calculations, there's the `Formula` step, and if worse comes to worst, you can always fall back on the `Modified Java Script Value` step.

Those steps should get you there. If you want a more exacting description, you'll have to post more detail about how your calculation works.